# Why does calling next() on an iterable object not work if I assign the generator function outside of __init__?

Tags: python, iterator, initialization, generator

When trying to write a class that acts as an Iterator I came across a problem. To take a deeper look into this I wrote two classes that implement `__next__()` (I am aware that `__iter__()` is needed to directly iterate over instances of the class but I chose to keep the problem as simple as possible by just directly calling `__next__()`). In addition to that I let `__next__()` return the `id` of the object that it is drawing the values from to make assumptions whether the values returned by `__next__()` stem from the same generator instance.

```py
from typing import Optional

class Gen1:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.content: generator = self.content()

    def __next__(self) -> Optional[tuple[int,int]]:
        try:
            return next(self.content), id(self.content)
        except StopIteration:
            return None

    def content(self) -> generator[int]:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3


class Gen2:
    def __next__(self) -> tuple[int,int]:
        x: generator = self.content()
        return next(x),id(x)

    def content(self) -> generator[int]:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
```

The only difference between the classes is that in the case of `Gen1` the function that generates the content of the Iterator `content()` is assigned to an instance attribute and in the case of `Gen2` it is assigned right inside the `__next__()` method.

In the past I always implemented these classes similar to `Gen1` and I was curious whether it is possible to create such a class without assigning the generator function to a variable inside `__init__()`.

If I create an instance of `Gen1` and call its `__next__()` a couple of times I would expect that it returns 1, then 2, then 3 and after that None and that all the values stem from the same generator object (the one created in the `__init__()`) and that is exactly what happens:

```py
gen1 = Gen1()
print(f"Class: {gen1.__class__.__name__}, id:{id(gen1)}")
for _ in range(0,5):
    print(next(gen1))
>>>
Class: Gen1, id:2912767032672
(1, 2912762151312)
(2, 2912762151312)
(3, 2912762151312)
None
None
```

Doing the same for `Gen2` I would expect one of two possible outcomes:

- The `__next__()` method always saves a 'fresh' image of the `content()` function, thus always returning 1, but having a different `id` every time.
- The `__next__()` method 'remembers' the generator and behaves exactly the same way it does as it was the case for `Gen1`

Let's see what happens:

```py
gen2 = Gen2()
print(f"Class: {gen2.__class__.__name__}, id:{id(gen2)}")
for _ in range(0,5):
    print(next(gen2))
>>>
Class: Gen2, id:2912767032096
(1, 2912766724464)
(1, 2912766724464)
(1, 2912766724464)
(1, 2912766724464)
(1, 2912766724464)
```

Interestingly, none of my expectations are true. The iteration fails and `__next__()` always returns 1. I could understand why this is the case if the 1 was coming from a different generator object every time but I cannot understand how `__next__()` is called on the same object and still does not iterate but starts over instead.
This gets even more weird if I create two seperate instances of `Gen2`:

```py
gen2 = Gen2()
gen3 = Gen2()
print(f"Class: {gen2.__class__.__name__}, id:{id(gen2)}")
for _ in range(0,5):
    print(next(gen2))
print('=====================')
print(f"Class: {gen3.__class__.__name__}, id:{id(gen3)}")
for _ in range(0,5):
    print(next(gen3))
>>>
Class: Gen2, id:1961519922000
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
=====================
Class: Gen2, id:1961519920944
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
(1, 1961519614320)
```

Now two **different** class instances (different `id`) return values from **the same generator** (same `id`) and it **still does not iterate**. This goes completely against my expectation and I have no idea how and why this is happening.
It seems that it is necessary for the generator function to be saved to an instance variable. Why is that?

### Summarizing my question:

How is it possible that the `__next__()` method is called on **the same object** (same `id`) and still does not properly iterate? What exactly happens while assigning the `content()` function to an instance attribute in the `__init__()` that makes the instance not 'forget' the state of the generator?

Is it even possible (ignoring for a second whether it would be useful or not) to force `__next__()` to remember the state of the generator or is there a way to come up with a `__next__()` that properly iterates without needing to assign the generator object returned by `content()` in a seperate variable outside the method itself? Does it even make sense to ask whether such a thing exists?

### Why do I care?

It is not solely because I want to have an iterable class even though there may not even be a justified use case for it. It seems that there are some more complex things happening regarding the `__next__()` method and/or what happens in the moment an object is actually created and/or assigned to a variable. I hope that an answer to this question will further my understanding of how some of these more intricate details of the language work.

Comment: "the same object (same id)" - and that's why `id` is a trap. Equal IDs **do not** mean you're looking at the same object if the lifetimes **don't overlap**.

Comment: You are creating new generator object each time with `x: generator = self.content()` right before calling next on it. That's why you are always getting `1`. In `Gen1` you create only a 1 generator.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the clarification. But that still leaves me with the question whether it is possible to create an iterator by directly utilizing the generator function without the need to save it to a variable that is outside of the scope of `__next__()`.